How can I use `hobby` path for filling a shape in TikZ?
I'm trying to fill a 3D shape specifically this dog-bone tensile test alloy using the hobby path for the corners in TikZ, but I want the fill to follow the curve.
Currently, I'm using a series of Bézier curves to create the fill following the outline of my shape but its not the same as the hobby because of tension and such, I want to use the hobby path to fill the area instead of using regular Bézier curves. How can I incorporate the hobby path within the \fill command to make the fill curve follow the path more smoothly, like it does in my original hobby path?
Though there might be alternative ways to reach the same result this is my primary problem.
Here’s the code I'm working with:
\documentclass[border=90pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=225, use Hobby shortcut]
    \Large
    \def\width{4}
    \def\gap{9}
    \def\main{8}
    \def\curvy{1.9}
    \def\depth{3}
    
    \def\n{3.3}
    \def\z{1/\n}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{1-\z}
    
    \coordinate (A) at (0,\main,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\width*\z-\width*\z*0.23,\main+\curvy-\curvy*0.7,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,0);
    
    \coordinate (A2) at (\width,\main,0);
    \coordinate (B2) at (\width*\s+\width*\z*0.23,\main+\curvy-\curvy*0.7,0);
    \coordinate (C2) at (\width*\s,\main+\curvy,0);
    
    \coordinate (A3) at (0,\main+\gap,0);
    \coordinate (B3) at (\width*\z-\width*\z*0.23,\main+\gap-\curvy+\curvy*0.7,0);
    \coordinate (C3) at (\width*\z,\main+\gap-\curvy,0);
    
    \coordinate (A4) at (\width,\main+\gap,0);
    \coordinate (B4) at (\width*\s+\width*\z*0.23,\main+\gap-\curvy+\curvy*0.7,0);
    \coordinate (C4) at (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,0);
    
    % Front face
        
    \fill[blue!20] 
        (0,0,0) -- (\width,0,0) -- (\width,\main,0) 
        .. controls (B2) .. (C2) -- 
        (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,0) 
        .. controls (B4) .. (A4) --
        (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,0) -- 
        (0,\main+\gap,0) .. controls (B3) .. (C3) --
        (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,0) .. controls (B) .. (A) --
        cycle;
     
    \draw[-] (0,0,0) -- (\width,0,0) node[midway] {3};
    \draw[-] (0,0,0) -- (0,\main,0) node[midway] {4};
    \draw[hobby,tension=3] (A) .. (B) .. (C);
    \draw[-] (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,0) -- (\width*\z,\main+\gap-\curvy,0) node[midway] {1};
    \draw[hobby,tension=3] (A3) .. (B3) .. (C3);
    \draw[-] (0,\main+\gap,0) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,0) node[midway] {6};
    \draw[-] (0,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) node[midway] {7};
    \draw[-] (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (\width,\main+\gap,0) node[midway] {8};
    \draw[hobby,tension=3] (A4) .. (B4) .. (C4);
    \draw[-] (\width*\s,\main+\curvy,0) -- (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,0) node[midway] {2};    
    \draw[hobby,tension=3] (A2) .. (B2) .. (C2);    
    \draw[-] (\width,0,0) -- (\width,\main,0) node[midway] {5};

    
    % Back face
    \draw[-,hobby,tension=3] (0,\main,\depth) .. (\width*\z-\width*\z*0.23,\main+\curvy-\curvy*0.7,\depth) .. (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,\depth);
    \draw[-,hobby,tension=3] (\width,\main,\depth) .. (\width*\s+\width*\z*0.23,\main+\curvy-\curvy*0.7,\depth) .. (\width*\s,\main+\curvy,\depth);
    \draw[-,hobby,tension=3] (0,\main+\gap,\depth) .. (\width*\z-\width*\z*0.23,\main+\gap-\curvy+\curvy*0.7,\depth) .. (\width*\z,\main+\gap-\curvy,\depth);
    \draw[-,hobby,tension=3] (\width,\main+\gap,\depth) .. (\width*\s+\width*\z*0.23,\main+\gap-\curvy+\curvy*0.7,\depth) .. (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,\depth);
    
    \draw[-] (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,\depth) -- (\width*\z,\main+\gap-\curvy,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width*\s,\main+\curvy,\depth) -- (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,0,\depth) -- (\width,0,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,0,\depth) -- (0,\main,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,0,\depth) -- (\width,\main,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,\main+\gap,\depth) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,2*\main+\gap,\depth) -- (\width,2*\main+\gap,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,2*\main+\gap,\depth) -- (\width,\main+\gap,\depth);
    
    % front and back faces
    \draw[-] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,0,0) -- (\width,0,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (\width,2*\main+\gap,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,\main,0) -- (0,\main,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,\main,0) -- (\width,\main,\depth);
    \draw[-] (0,\main+\gap,0) -- (0,\main+\gap,\depth);
    \draw[-] (\width,\main+\gap,0) -- (\width,\main+\gap,\depth);
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

While it seems large the only relevant part to my problem is the fill of the front face here:
    \fill[blue!20] 
        (0,0,0) -- (\width,0,0) -- (\width,\main,0) 
        .. controls (B2) .. (C2) -- 
        (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,0) 
        .. controls (B4) .. (A4) --
        (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,0) -- 
        (0,\main+\gap,0) .. controls (B3) .. (C3) --
        (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,0) .. controls (B) .. (A) --
        cycle;

I want the curve in the \fill command to behave like the hobby path and create a smooth, continuous fill, rather than having jagged edges or using multiple control points. What modifications do I need to make to achieve this effect?
Here is the compile also


you could also (probably) draw and fill at the same time and/or save paths for reuse. (hobby is an expensive algorithm, as I'm sure you know.)

@cfr I legit tried both of those options, but the fills end up glitching with weird clipping issues. also i get that using hobby to get that curve may be a touch excessive, but hey, I'll save it as an ace for future reference or when its actually needed. Thank you for not leaving my post in the dark; much appreciated.

I managed to solve the issue! The key was incorporating the to[hobby,tension=3] syntax directly into the \fill command. By doing so, I was able to ensure that the curves in the fill path followed the smooth, continuous behavior of the Hobby algorithm, just like I wanted.
Here's the updated code for the front face fill:
\fill[blue!20] 
    (0,0,0) -- (\width,0,0) -- (\width,\main,0) 
    to[hobby,tension=3] (A2) .. (B2) .. (C2) -- 
    (\width*\s,\main+\gap-\curvy,0) 
    to[hobby,tension=3] (C4) .. (B4) .. (A4) --
    (\width,2*\main+\gap,0) -- (0,2*\main+\gap,0) -- 
    (0,\main+\gap,0) to[hobby,tension=3] (A3) .. (B3) .. (C3) --
    (\width*\z,\main+\curvy,0) to[hobby,tension=3] (C) .. (B) .. (A) --
    cycle;

This allows the fill path to follow the same smooth curvature as the hobby paths used in the face. It avoids the jagged edges or multiple control points of that a Bézier curves would achieve and gives a more consistent and aesthetically pleasing result relative to the hobby.
Hopefully, this helps anyone facing a similar issue! 
